# Preselect country in WooCommerce Checkout Page with Geolocation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, checkout

I need to select the country field with WooCommerce geolocation in the checkout field.

The user should still be able to change this.

How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong in your installation as if you have choose the option in Woocommerce settings "General options" section for **"Default customer location"** as **"Geolocate"** *(or "Geolocate with page caching support")*, Woocommerce do that by default **without any code needed**. See:

[image]

Related threads for ["Woocommerce Geolocation" on StackOver Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D%20WC_Geolocation).

Comment: Could this be an issue with country as a "Required Field"?

Comment: @cysus No… There is something else that is making trouble apparently. By default when "Geolocate" is set for customers, everything works fine without any need. Some customization made by you, your theme or a third party plugin is the guilty. But you are the only one to be able to find out which one is guilty.

Comment: Thanks. After deactivating all plugins I found out that a plugin was responsible for this bug: 

Stripe Payment Gateway Plugin for WooCommerce (Credit Card, Debit Card, AliPay, Apple Pay) by xAdapter

As there is a much better alternative from Woocommerce itself, I deleted the buggy plugin and it works now as expected.